# Exporting unequal number of array output to a file using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have `keys` and `data` [sic] as follows, which I need to export in a text file.

```
keys = %w[ID No time]
Data = ["a", ["1", "2", "3", "4"], 20]
```

My desired output is:

```
ID   No    time
a    1      20
a    2      20
a    3      20
a    4      20
```

I had attempted the following code so far:

```
File.open('test1.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write Data.join("\t")}
```

But it doesn't show my desired output.

Any direction regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Update : 
Just extending the question :

if there are same Keys and a block of Data (Data1,Data2, Data3 ,...) how to efficiently concatenate and export the total output to a text file?

```
Data1 = [a, [1, 2, 3, 4], 20]
Data2 = [b,[5,6,7,8],8]
Data3 =[c,[9,10,11,13],10]
```

Comment: Is it the case that the `id` is always the first element, `time` is always the last one and everything in the middle is different `No`s?

Comment: @ndn , Many thanks for your solution. yes. But, please check the data array again in my question(sorry, I had updated it !). The "No" values are separated by an array inside the array.In that case, What adjustments are needed in your coding?

Comment: ok, I updated my answer. It was just a matter of removing a `*`.

Comment: It worked! thanks , @ndn

Comment: Did you really expect your code to produce the expected output? You don't even use `keys`.

Comment: @Stefan, the keys have been used as header, and values of the keys are stored in the data array, thanks.

Comment: `[keys].concat([Data.first].product(Data[1], [Data[2]]))` will get you the rows you are looking for.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I like your suggestion. For greater generality one could write `d = Data.map { |d| [*d] }; [keys].concat(d.shift.product(*d))`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland , thanks for your idea. I have a question, if there are same Keys and a block of  Data (Data1,Data2, Data3 ,...) how to efficiently concatenate and export the total output to a text file?

Comment: Rubz, if `arr = [keys].concat(d.shift.product(*d))` in my comment above and you want to write a file with comma-deleted values,this will do it: `File.open("test","w") { |fp| arr.each { |a| fp.puts a.join(',') } }`. To see what was written, `puts File.read("test")` displays the following five lines: `D,No,time`, `a,1,20`, `a,2,20`, `a,3,20`, `a,4,20`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'csv'

keys = %w(ID No time)
data = ['a', [1, 2, 3, 4], 20]

id, numbers, time = data
CSV.open('test1.txt', 'w', headers: keys, write_headers: true, col_sep: "\t") do |csv|
  numbers.each do |number|
    csv << [id, number, time]
  end
end
```

Comment: The formatting is slightly off, but I assume that is of no concern to the OP. Namely, the `2`s in `20` are left-aligned with the `"t"` in `time`, rather than with the `"i"` in `"time"` (i.e., centred under `"time"`, presumably).

Answer (score 1):

Without using `csv` library:

```
keys = %w[ID No time]
data = ["a", ["1", "2", "3", "4"], 20]

File.open('test1.txt', 'w') do |file|
  file.write(keys.join("\t")+"\n")
  data[1].map { |x| file.write("#{data[0]}\t#{x}\t#{data[2]}\n") }
end
```

For multiple data:

```
data_array = []
data_array << data1
data_array << data2
data_array << data3
.....
```

Which results data_array as:

```
data_array = [['a', [1, 2, 3, 4], 20], ['b',[5,6,7,8],8], ['c',[9,10,11,13],10]]

File.open('test1.txt', 'w') do |file|
  file.write(keys.join("\t")+"\n")
  data_array.each do |data|
    data[1].map { |x| file.write("#{data[0]}\t#{x}\t#{data[2]}\n") }
  end
end
```

Comment: @Rubz There are lots of other ways as well to handle with multiple data sets. Best method depends on how you construct each data array.

Answer (score 0):

Just extending the question :

if there are same Keys and a block of Data (Data1,Data2, Data3 ,...) how to efficiently concatenate and export the total output to a text file?

```
Data1 = [a, [1, 2, 3, 4], 20]
Data2 = [b,[5,6,7,8],8]
Data3 =[c,[9,10,11,13],10]
```

Comment: You can edit the question with an `Update` tag and ask it there instead of asking this in the answers section.

Comment: You just have to add a loop if its an array. See my updated answer.

Comment: @AshikSalman the block of  Data might contain for example 500 of Data array , not just three , please advice by updating the code . Thanks in advance .